# How to make a centered section clickable?

Tags: html, css

I simply want to make a centered section clickable. I used margin auto to center my section but now the margins are clickable too. Should I use flex-box or something to center the section so that there's no more margin or there is an other way? What's the best practice here?

```html
  <main>
    <a href="#">
      <section>
          <div class="content">
            <h2>some stuff</h2>
            <h1>title</h1>
            <img src="img/arrow.svg" alt="arrow" width="30">
          </div>
       </section>
     </a>
  </main>
```

```css
        section {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
        }
```

Here's a JSFiddle : [Clickable centered section](https://jsfiddle.net/broc4jme/)

Comment: Which part do you want to be clickable? The whole `.content` `<div>`, or one of the headers? You have the `<a>` tag wrapped around the `<section>`... which is `1000px` wide, so yes, your clickable area will be `1000px`. Is this not what you want? Could you please clarify exactly what you want to be able to click on, and what you do not want to be able to click on?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by clickable? What to want to happen when this `div` is clicked?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I want to do is make the whole blue section in my JSFiddlle clickable (send me to another page). I centered this section using margin: auto, wich means the section have margins. The margins are clickable too. I want to prevent this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've another solution for you. Just add the following code to your css. You can try this.

```
  a {
      display: block;
      height: fit-content;
      width: fit-content;
      margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
    }
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
}

section {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.25), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

section:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
}

section.logofolio {
  background-color: #3D75E3;
}

section .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 100px 100px;
}

section h1 {
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

section h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

section img {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main class="work">
  <p style="text-align: center">
  As you can see the margins are clickable too!
  </p>
  <a href="#">
    <section class="logofolio">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>some stuff</h2>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <img src="img/arrow.svg" alt="arrow" width="30">
      </div>
    </section>
  </a>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Of course IE and Edge don't support it!

Comment: Oh. Yes. I forgot to say that. @XavierGodbout

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for you. I used absolute positioning to center the div. I separated my code using comments. You can check that. Hope it will be helpful.

```css
section {
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 400px;
            
            /*Edited portion starts*/
            
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            /* margin: 0 auto 100px auto; */
            
            /*Edited portion ends*/
            
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.25), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
            &:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
            }
            .content {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 0 0 100px 100px;
                h1 {
                    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 3rem;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                }
                h2 {
                    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 0.8rem;
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                }
                img {
                    padding-top: 10px;
                }
            }
        }
        section.logofolio {
            background-color: #3D75E3;
        }
```

```html
<main class="work">

  <a href="#">
    <section class="logofolio">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>some stuff</h2>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <img src="img/arrow.svg" alt="arrow" width="30">
      </div>
    </section>
  </a>
  
</main>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it almost worked for me. Unfortunately I have css transition on those section and the translateX(50%) kinda messes them up. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @XavierGodbout I've posted another solution as a new answer. Try this. I think this will not mess your other elements. Thank you. :)